# Play Games plugin for unity master(Setup)

Tags: unity-game-engine, java-8, google-play-services

Hi all I would like to start using google play services in my game. Since friday I am trying to solve this error. When I setting up services in Unity editor. I have this error:

> Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\bin\jar.exe', CommandLine='xvf
>   "G:\Buldings\Assets\Plugins\Android\firebase-common-9.0.2.aar"',
>   CurrentDirectory='G:\Buldings\Assets\Plugins\Android\firebase-common-9.0.2'
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   () (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
>   GooglePlayServices.DefaultResolver.ProcessAar (System.String dir,
>   System.String aarFile) (at
>   Assets/PlayServicesResolver/Editor/DefaultResolver.cs:213) Rethrow as
>   TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation. System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder,
>   System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
>   (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
>   UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal.PostprocessAllAssets
>   (System.String[] importedAssets, System.String[] addedAssets,
>   System.String[] deletedAssets, System.String[] movedAssets,
>   System.String[] movedFromPathAssets) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetPostprocessor.cs:27)

Below you can find some pictures with my problem. Do you have some idea how to solve it ?

[image]

[image]

Thanks for all.

Comment: Hello, I am not very sure that the error you are getting has anything related to game-play-services (the error comes from firebase). however I think that you need to use another constant class name. "test" isn't valid. Try using GPGSyourgamename. Let me know.

Comment: You have absolutely right thank you for this information. Where you get this information could you give me your source?

Comment: I had the same issue when I started using this plugin :P